# Memory copy through pointers misses data sometimes

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, copy, memory-address

I am writing a simple c++ program to copy data from a buffer to a dedicated memory location. Whenever the buffer gets updated, I run the following loop:

```
tempPtr= (u64 *) buffer;
for (j=0; j<buffer_length; j++){
    destinationPtr[i+j]=buffer[j];
}
i=i+j;
```

The problem is, sometimes this code works fine, and sometimes it misses chunks of data. I do not know what is going on here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot use memcpy, because I am running the code on FPGA and memcpy has poor performance on FPGA...

Comment: Alignment issues ?

Comment: Aliasing violation, type punning and undefined behaviour?

Comment: Are you able to try memcpy or using unsigned char, just for diagnostic purposes, to see if the problem is affected?

Comment: for (j=0; j<buffer_length * sizeof(u64); j++){((unsigned char*)destinationPtr)[i * sizeof(u64)+j]=((unsigned char*)buffer)[j]; }

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry guys, just after posting the question, I found out that the problem was not with copying memory, but with variable buffer sizes... The buffer was not getting updated right.. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Delete the question or provide the answer yourself and accept it, please. Let's keep things organized for other users seeking answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting the question, I found out that the problem was not with copying memory, but with variable buffer sizes... The buffer size was not the multiple of data to be copied. That resulted in skipping of some chunks.